# Trigger to delete field records every year on a day

Tags: trigger, after-trigger

I have to delete records on a field on 10th Jan of every year using a trigger. I wrote the trigger below for that purpose

```
trigger mytrigger on Account (after insert) {
    Account acc = [select Date from Account where id =:trigger.new[0].id];
    delete acc;
}
```

How to add the condition to delete the record on 10th Jan

Comment: Don't use trigger for this purpose, use scheduled jobs. Trigger runs in real-time which defeats the use case. I suggest you go through https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/asynchronous_apex/async_apex_scheduled, this module to understand more on scheduled class and how will that help you to achieve the use case.

Comment: Can we delete the data in the Date field of the account using the apex class instead of deleting the whole account? As the delete Scope(); deletes the entire account. It should only delete the data in Date field

Comment: You can update the date field to null, if you want, in the execute method in the answer posted by sfdcfox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triggers can only execute the instant that a record is created, modified, or deleted. As such, you cannot delete records on a schedule using a trigger. You would either want to use a Schedulable class that is called on the 10th of January every year, or set a Process Builder Scheduled Action. Note that Process Builder Scheduled Actions are limited to how many can fire in an hour, so the Schedulable class would be ideal if you may have thousands or even millions of records to update.

```
public class ScheduledDeletion implements Scheduble, Database.Batchable<sObject> {
    public void execute(SchedualbleContext context) {
        Database.executeBatch(this);
    }
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([
            SELECT Id FROM Account
        ]);
    }
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, Account[] scope) {
        delete scope;
    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {

    }
}
```

Which you then schedule to execute every year:

```
System.scheduleJob('DeleteAnnually','0 0 0 10 1 ?',new ScheduledDeletion());
```

You can do this with an Execute Anonymous script or by writing something into  a UI.

Again, you can't do this with a trigger; you need to use a Schedulable class to perform actions on a schedule.

Comment: Can we delete the data in the Date field of the account using the apex class instead of deleting the whole account?
As the delete Scope(); deletes the entire account. It should only delete the data in Date field

Comment: @sfdc4321 Sure: `for(Account record: scope) { record.Field = null; } update scope;`